# SSL error while pip3 install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am new to coding. While i try to install python-forecastio using pip3 for python3,it gives me below error.

```
$ sudo pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org    python-forecastio

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Collecting python-forecastio

  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-forecastio/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-forecastio (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for python-forecastio
```

Comment: The reason is that there is no OpenSSL related software installed,

Try  yum install openssl openssl-devel

Then everything works well.

Comment: What kind of setup are you running on that doesn't have the SSL module built-in?

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is, as you may have guessed, the SSL module is not available.
So the simple way to fix the problem is to reinstall python. But the alternative is to run this simple line of code: `import ssl`. If you get an error you will know your python 3 installation is corrupt so you need to reinstall python, or if you don't get an error try using `easy_install-3.x (what ever the module or link you want)`(Use the specific python you have installed version in place of "x"). Hope I helped!

-Zeus